# How to define 'tab' delimiter with 'cut' in Bash?

Tags: bash, cut

Here is an example of using `cut` to break input into fields using a space delimiter, and obtaining the second field:

`cut -f2 -d' '`

How can the delimiter be defined as a tab, instead of a space?

Comment: [Using cut with unprintable delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785283/using-cut-with-unprintable-delimiters) (stackoverflow)

Comment: Tab is a default delimiter. cut -f 2

Answer (score 511, accepted):

Two ways:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to use "verbatim" [quoted insert](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Text.html).

```
cut -f2 -d'   ' infile
```

or write it like this to use [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html):

```
cut -f2 -d$'\t' infile
```

The `$'...'` form of quotes isn't part of the POSIX shell language ([not yet](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=249)), but works at least in ksh, mksh, zsh and Busybox in addition to Bash.

Comment: Neither works in Windows (e.g., Git Bash) obviously. Use @Mikel's answer there (default delimiter is tab, simply omit `-d` argument).

Comment: @AhmedFasih, both work in Cygwin, though (tested)

Comment: [What does it mean to have a $“dollarsign-prefixed string” in a script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48122/85163)

Comment: @poige, that comes from `ksh93`, not `bash`. That's supported by ksh93, zsh, bash, mksh and FreeBSD sh at least ([it might make it to the next major reversion of the POSIX standard specification for `sh`](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=249)).

Comment: @micurb That's ANSI-C quoting: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html

Comment: you can also use Ctrl-q instead of Ctrl-v

Comment: @AhmedFasih the 2nd option (-d $'\t' ) works for me in git bash on windows.

Comment: * Does not work in zsh

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35387/391735

Answer (score 316):

Tab is the default.

See the [cut man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/).

```
-d delim
         Use delim as the field delimiter character instead of the tab
         character.
```

So you can just write

```
cut -f 2
```

Comment: But it is probably always safer to mention such flags explicitly, for both readability and portability. I can imagine some people designing a `cut` for Windows would not follow the complete standard.

Comment: This should be accepted answer: simplest code, simplest explanation. ya nailed it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpNTHl7y45Y

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, if someone writes a version of `cut` for Windows and doesn't follow the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) for it, there is no reason to assume that *any* POSIX script will work with that system.  Stick to POSIX-specified features.  Don't try to allow for hypothetical future non-compliant implementations; that's not what "portability" means.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Additionally, `cut -f 2` is way more readable than `cut -d'    ' -f 2` or `cut -d$'\t' -f 2`

Answer (score 19):

```
awk -F '\t' '{ print $2 }' inputfile
```

This extracts the second tab-delimited field of each line of input from `inputfile`.

Comment: The OP was specifically asking about `cut`.  Moreover, `cut(1)` is *waaay* faster than `awk(1)`.

Answer (score 10):

More generically, without requiring any invisible characters: Use `tr` to convert the delimiters to a format that can be specified more easily to `cut`.

```
$ echo -e "a\tb\tc" |tr '\t' ' ' |cut -d' ' -f2
b
```

`tr` is a simple, but powerful, character matching and replacement tool.

Comment: But what if the input is `abc(space)def(tab)ghi`? Your answer will yield `def`, but it should yield `ghi`.  Similarly, if the input is `ABC(tab)DEF(space)GHI`, your answer will yield `DEF`, but it should yield ``DEF(space)GHI``.

Comment: @G-Man: The space delimiter was only an example.  Use whatever delimiter is appropriate for your data -- a comma for example.  `echo -e "abc\tdef ghi" |tr '\t' ',' |cut -d',' -f2`

Comment: ...But, yeah, if the delimiter must be a tab, then my approach won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, one could wrap cut in a function.

```
function getColumns ()
{
    local -r delimiter="${1:?}"
    local -r columns="${2:?}"

    if [[ "$delimiter" == '\t' || "$delimter" == "tab" ]]; then
        cut "--fields=${columns}"
        return
    fi

    cut "--delimiter=${delimiter}" "--fields=${columns}" 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I use `TAB` and `cut` in these ways:

```
# quote the whole thing, use TAB escape
cut "-d\t" -f 2
# just quote the tab escape 
cut -d "\t" -f 2
# Use Ctrl-V to quote Ctrl-I (TAB is Ctrl-I, see man ascii)
cut -d^V^I -f 2
```

Comment: The `cut` utility does not understand the `\t` as tab.

Comment: @Kusalananda Show the failure.  By quoting , the `"\t"` is interpreted by the shell, which does understand backslash-escapes, and `$(...)`, and ... What's your `$SHELL` or `getent passwd $(id -u) | cut "-d:" -f6`. Also `cat --show-all datafile | head -n 10`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Just try it yourself in any POSIX shell: `printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' 1 2 3 | cut -d "\t" -f 2` (will not extract the `2` in the 2nd column).  Just use `cut` without the `-d` option (tab is the default delimiter).

Comment: In fact coreutils `cut` fails when given `-d "\t"` or `"-d\t"`: “cut: the delimiter must be a single character”.