# What does it mean to have a $"dollarsign-prefixed string" in a script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, quoting

I just saw this in an init script:

```
echo $"Stopping Apache"
```

What is that dollar-sign for?

#### My research so far:

I found this in the bash manual:

> *extquote*
>
> > If set, `$'string'` and `$"string"` quoting is performed within `${parameter}` expansions enclosed in double quotes.  This option is enabled by default.

...but I'm not finding any difference between strings with and without the `$` prefix:

```
$ echo "I am in $PWD"
I am in /var/shared/home/southworth/qed
$ echo $"I am in $PWD"
I am in /var/shared/home/southworth/qed
$ echo $"I am in ${PWD}"
I am in /var/shared/home/southworth/qed
$ echo "I am in ${PWD}"
I am in /var/shared/home/southworth/qed
$ echo 'I am in ${PWD}'
I am in ${PWD}
$ echo $'I am in ${PWD}'
I am in ${PWD}
$ echo $'I am in $PWD'
I am in $PWD
```

Answer (score 164, accepted):

There are two different things going on here, both documented in the `bash` manual

## $'

Dollar-sign single quote is a special form of quoting:

[ANSI C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

## $"

Dollar-sign double-quote is for localization:

[Locale translation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Locale-Translation.html)

> A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign (‘$’) will cause the string to be translated according to the current locale. If the current locale is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored. If the string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.

Comment: Thanks for the example. What I don't understand is - why did ANSI support `$''` when you can just use `""`? I'm sure there's a reason and for my understanding it would be good to know.

Comment: I think the behavior of "\n" vs $'\n' is different but I'm still confused.

Comment: `""` does not interpret that much. Try `$'\x31'` vs. `"\x31"`.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat, Another difference is: `"$variable\n"` will result in the contents of the variable followed by a newline, whereas `$'$variable\n'` will result in $variable followed by a newline. So, if you want to avoid escaping dollar signs and double quotes in a string and still be able to escape single quotes (for example if you are passing a complex command to a specific shell from within a bash script), then `$''` is the way to go.

Comment: Ah yes I remember that Chinese characters' escape codes can be tab completed if you use dollar syntax. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any example of when `$"..."` is useful? I found the docs, too, but I do not really understand what they say. What does it mean to translate a string according to the current locale? I know what locale is, BTW.

Comment: @Palec This is for human language translation but in order for it to work you have to go through a lot of steps to set up translation files. More info under [Creating Internationalized Scripts](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Locale-Translation) which for some reason is missing from the link above.

Answer (score 36):

When a string is expanded inside of `$''`, the escape sequences are interpreted. From the manpage:

```
Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to
string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by  the
ANSI  C  standard.
```

An easy example is the \n escape sequence for a newline:

```
$ echo 'foo\n'
foo\n
$ echo $'foo\n'
foo

$
```

Note: You may get different results in other shells as `echo` may interpret escape sequences without providing options.

Comment: There is no mention of `$"..."`, as per the question.

Answer (score -5):

You're misinterpreting the manual.  You'll only see an effect when a $-quoted string is *inside* a `${parameter}` expansion.

```
$ echo "${v:-'ab\ncd'}"
'ab\ncd'
$ echo "${v:-$'ab\ncd'}"
ab
cd
```

Source and further reading: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2005-10/msg00017.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: `$"…"` is something different.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is wrong: there is no need to use `${}` expansion to make use of ANSI quoting. Check for yourself: `echo $'ab\ncd'`

Comment: I think this answer was trying to explain `extquote` incorrectly instead of what the question was asking.

Comment: `"${...}"` is different than `$"..."`