# Is it possible to do a here-document in one line or echo verbatim?

Tags: escape-characters, echo, here-document

I often find myself testing out a command (e.g. `cat file | awk 'stuff'`) in the shell and when I'm satisfied with the way it works, I append the command to a script file.

Let's say this is the command I created `cat file.txt | awk -F '|' '$3 == "\"0\""'`

How can I quickly echo that to a file without having to escape stuff first and without having to use the mouse?

Is there a way to do something like

`echo --verbatim the_command_with_lots_of_quotes_and_everything >> file.sh`

or

`cat <<'EOF'\n the_command \n EOF >> file.sh` ?

Comment: `set -v; { # commands\n} 2>>file; set -`; or `fc -nl -0`

Comment: Do you want to store the command only or also the output by command?

Comment: cat >> file.sh;  (type command here); (type control-D here)

Answer (score 4):

Not so quick, but zsh (and bash maybe?) has this feature called `fc`, I'm not sure what it stands for but if you type it, it seems to open up the command in whatever your `$EDITOR` is.

Or maybe you could do `history | tail -1 >> file`.

In terms of doing a heredoc in one line, this:

```
~$ echo -e "cat << EOF\nhello\n12345\nEOF\n" | sh
hello
12345
```

is the closest I can think of.

Comment: this is slightly more clear to me: `eval $'cat << DL > /home/user/test \nLine1\nLine2\nDL'` (DL is the delimiter in a Heredoc `cat << EOF > file.txt \nLine1\nLine2\nEOF` https://linuxize.com/post/bash-heredoc/) $'..' is an ANSI C string https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48106/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-dollarsign-prefixed-string-in-a-script "Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard."