# Single line heredocument - Possible in Bash?

Tags: here-document, here-string

I desire to run a `cat` heredocument in a single row instead the natural syntax of 3 rows (opener, content, and delimiter). My need to do so is mostly aesthetic as the redirected content aimed aimed to be part of a handbook text file and I would like to save as much rows as I can, in that particular file).

Doing `cat <<< TEST > ~/myRep/tiesto tiesto TEST` (what I would normally split for 3 parts) results in an errors:

> tiesto: No such file or direcotry
>
> TEST: No such file or directory.

Is it even possible to execute one-row heredocuments in Bash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do a here-document in one line or echo verbatim?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256539/is-it-possible-to-do-a-here-document-in-one-line-or-echo-verbatim)

Comment: It seems to me his answer isn't focused on either `heredocument` or `awk`. I ask only on heredocuments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, but you'd be using a an [*here-string*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) rather than a *here-document*:

```
cat >"$HOME/myRep/tiesto" <<<'tiesto'
```

This will send the string `tiesto` to `cat` on its standard input, and it will write the string to the file `$HOME/myRep/tiesto` through a redirection of its standard output.

Note that here-strings are not standard but are implemented by at least `zsh` (where it comes from, at the same time as the UNIX version of `rc`, though that `rc` and its derivatives like `es` or `akanga` don't add an extra newline character in the end),  `ksh93`, `bash`, `mksh` and `yash`.

Answer (score 2):

You could put a here-document (as opposed to a here-string), on a single line, by using:

```
eval $'cat << TEST > ~/myRep/tiesto\ntiesto\nTEST'
```

Technically, that's one line of code, but the `$'...'` will expand into a new 3 line code that is `eval`uated again.

Using `eval`, you can always put any shell code on one line.

With shells that don't support `$'...'`, you can do:

```
eval "$(printf 'NL="\n"')"; eval "cat << TEST > ~/myRep/tiesto${NL}tiesto${NL}TEST"
```

Or

```
eval "$(printf 'cat << TEST > ~/myRep/tiesto\ntiesto\nTEST')"
```

Of course here,

```
echo tiesto > ~/myRep/tiesto
```

would be a lot simpler. Or for multiple lines:

```
printf '%s\n' "line 1" "line 2" > ~/myRep/tiesto
```

Comment: this is slightly more clear to me: `eval $'cat << DL > /home/user/test \nLine1\nLine2\nDL'` (DL is the delimiter in a Heredoc `cat << EOF > file.txt \nLine1\nLine2\nEOF` https://linuxize.com/post/bash-heredoc/) $'..' is an ANSI C string https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48106/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-dollarsign-prefixed-string-in-a-script "Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard."