# Example for $"..."

Tags: bash

As I was searching for an answer regarding what is `$"..."` , I came across [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48122/224025)

The answer although tells what's `$"..."` but does not clarify with an example, it mentions about **locale** but I didn't understand that either which is why I still don't understand what is the purpose of `$"..."` , where do people use it and what do people use it for ?

I am looking for an example that explain this.

Comment: There is [a whole example here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localization.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used to use your [locale settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/149111/135943) to allow the shell to translate text into the current locale  (e. g. having `LANGUAGE=de_DE echo $"Good morning"` yield `Guten Morgen`).  There is a fair amount of reading on how to set this up [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/098#Translate_the_strings).

Comment: What is locale ? Just the language settings ? So is $"..." used just for displaying text in the language the user selected as preference while installing the OS?

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/149111/135943