# 'Invalid or incomplete multbyte or wide character' with 'column'

Tags: text-processing, columns

I'm on a Linux system and I'm trying to use 'column' on a file that I've spiked with an extended character to use as the separator.  Reason being that any normal printing character is liable to show up where I don't want separation to occur, so by using 'sed' to find only those places where I do what the columns to separate, and adding an extended character at those places, then using that same extended character as the 'column' separator I should be OK.
Alas, trying to use hex character AE:

```
$ column -ts\xAE junk1  
column: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

... or any other extended character doesn't work and I've tried every combination of quotes and other tricks I can think of.  But ts sounds like 'column' is open to using extended characters, so I just have to enter the thing properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print Unicode lower case æ, which is u00E6, you can use this:

```
$ printf '\u00E6\n' 
æ
```

So, if your file looks like this:

```
$ printf 'foobarbaz\u00E6bar\u00E6baz bar something else whohooo!\n' 
foobarbazæbaræbaz bar something else whohooo!
```

You could use column like so:

```
$ printf 'foobarbaz\u00E6bar\u00E6baz bar something else whohooo!\n' | 
    column -ts$'\u00E6' -o "::::::::"
foobarbaz::::::::bar::::::::baz bar something else whohooo!
```

Note the ANSI escape format (`$'characterCode'`); see [What does it mean to have a $"dollarsign-prefixed string" in a script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48106/86440) I used `-o "::::::::"` so you can easily see the columns.

Comment: @RayAndrews what is `\x7f` supposed to be? If you expect it to be a newline, you again need to use ANSI escaping: `-ts $'\x7f'`.

Comment: Yeah those were my failed efforts.  Sheesh, you'd think the man page would be more helpful.