# What '\t' mean with 'tab' delimiter with 'cut' in BASH

Tags: bash, cut, tabulation

In this command :

```
cut -f2 -d$'\t'
```

(`'\t'`) what is it mean ?
i saw it another question, i got the idea about "tab" delimiter but still want to know `'\t'` shortcut or sign or command for something

[How to define 'tab' delimiter with 'cut' in BASH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35369/how-to-define-tab-delimiter-with-cut-in-bash?newreg=3fbe8b46d35148c6976206ef2d53e4e5)

Answer (score 2):

The horizontal tabulator character is a character that by default brings the cursor up to the next multiple of eight spaces when it's outputted.

Example:

```
$ printf '1234567*1234567*\na\thello\tthere\n'
1234567*1234567*
a       hello   there
```

As you can see above, for each tab character, the cursor is forwarded to the next multiple of eight spaces.

The tab character is written as `\t` in the C programming language.  Printing a string containing `\t` with `printf` in the shell or with `printf()` in C (and in many other places) produces a horizontal tab character in place of the two characters `\` and `t`.

In the `bash` shell, `$'...'` is a special "C escape string".  Within it, escape sequences like `\t` (for tab) or `\n` (for newline) are treated just like in `printf()` in the C language.  This is described in the `bash` manual in the section titled "QUOTING".

With `cut -d $'\t'` you tell `cut` to use tab as the delimiter when cutting the fields of the input data.  However, this happens to be the *default* delimiter that `cut` will use if you don't use `-d` at all, so `-d $'\t'` is not needed in your command.

Comment: Straight to the Point, Well explained, thanks a lot, now i know, they are calling -Escape sequences- of course thanks to you